# Is it possible to have a config key be the result of a variable interpolation in Hydra?

Tags: python, fb-hydra, omegaconf

Assuming the following config structure:

```
config.yaml
|-model
|  |--default.yaml
|
|-data
   |--default.yaml
```

`config.yaml` :

```
defaults:
  - model: default
  - data: default
```

`model/default.yaml` :

```
...
x_label: some_label
...
```

The following doesn't work:

`data/default.yaml`:

```
...
loaders:
  ${model.x_label}:
    param1: a
    param2: b
...
```

Is there a way to make something like this work? Or an equivalent alternative?

Comment: Currently this is unspported in Hydra/OmegaConf; values can be interpolations, but keys cannot.

Answer (score 1):

Currently this is unspported in Hydra/OmegaConf; values can be interpolations, but keys cannot.

As a workaround, consider the following for your `data/default.yaml` file:

```yaml
...
loaders:
  label: ${model.x_label}
  params:
    param1: a
    param2: b
...
```